# MPMoviePlayerController play/pause toggle issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I have used MPMoviePlayerController in my application to play selected video. There is also facility to start video from different location like from 10 min, 20 min, 40 min etc.

**Problem in iOS 7:**

The problem is when video is played I am able to pause it but it does not resume after pausing. And also the pause button does not turn into play button. After clicking pause button   none of the notification like "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification" get invoked. And same problem occurs when video is playing in fullscreen mode.

**Problem in iOS 6:**

Here only problem is that pause button does not turn into play button. Here video pause and resume works properly in fullscreenmode also.

**one strange behaviour:**

For one video when I play it from 40 min it just works perfectly. None of the above issues occur for it. But same video does not work when played from starting or 10,20 min durations.

I have searched a lot but I found only one post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229560/mpmovieplayer-standard-interface-play-pause-status-reflection-issue) related to this issue. But this solution is not working for me.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: i  m facing same issue in iOS8.4 . Any update @ViruMax

Comment: not yet :|, we have kept it aside. I think it is related to loading time the movie player takes or the operations get performed before playing video.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any idea how to fix this
?

Comment: @nhenrique please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVPlayer` as `MPMoviePlayer` is now  deprecated.

Comment: thank you. Just one more question, do you have any problems with AVPlayer controls? Only the fullscreen button is working, all the others are "disabled"

Comment: No I have not faced such issue yet.